# Using a hash table to represent more specific data structures?

Tags: data-structures, hashtable

I know that [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) can be used to store:

- [Graphs](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/): each vertex is associated with its adjacent vertices.
- [Sparse matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Dictionary_of_keys_.28DOK.29): a DOK (dictionary of keys) mapping (row, column)-pairs to the value of the elements.
- [Sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Sets): each element is associated with `nil`.
- [Multisets (or Bags)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset): each element is associated with its multiplicity.

What other data structures (for instance, in [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures)) may be efficiently represented by a hash table?

Comment: I would mention probablilistic data structures (Bloom Filter, Quitient Filter) which are basically hash tables, in some sense.

Comment: Questions which assume enumerations as answers, or asked purposely to make the list of *something*, doesn't fit SO's QA format.